# Accessing cell value of a WMS raster served as ol.layer.Image from OpenLayers

Tags: raster, openlayers, mapserver, getfeatureinfo, pixel

I would like to access the value of the raster cell on clicked location (sort of an identify tool) of a raster displayed in a webapp as ol.layer.Image via MapServer. I have set the .map file of the MapServer to include TEMPLATE link and template.html.

Can anyone help me with the OpenLayers code to access and display the value of the cell?

Comment: It seems a standard GetFeatureInfo request like ~ https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html

Comment: Hi, thanks but I solved this a long time ago. And yes you are absolutely right